# UITableViewController Content not appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

My content does not appear in the table cells during simulation even after i have changed them all to Table view controllers and made them static cells and throws me the error `Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances` i have not added in any code yet so i cant think of what could be wrong Help greatly needed.

Comment: Adding some screenshots on what you're doing may help define the problem.

Comment: post code what you tried :)

Comment: put relavent code/ screenshots here :)

Comment: show some code or screen shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't update the Storyboard.  Did you change the view controller class in the storyboard to `UITableViewController` or your subclass?  Somewhere the parent of your static tableview isn't pointing to your `UITableView` class.